# How can I cast or convert boost bind to C function pointer?

Tags: c++, boost

Suppose I have this:

```
void func(WCHAR* pythonStatement) {
  // Do something with pythonStatement
}
```

And I need to convert it to void function(void) like this:

```
bind(func, TEXT("console.write('test')"))
```

Now I have struct like this:

```
typedef void (__cdecl * PFUNCPLUGINCMD)();

struct FuncItem {
PFUNCPLUGINCMD pFunc;
    // ...
};
```

How can I set the pFunc of my struct to `bind(func, "something")`? Bind returns lambda_functor not a function pointer, so how can I cast this functor to function pointer?

Thanks.

---

**Ended up using [the wrapping "solution"](https://github.com/Ciantic/NppyPluginDll/blob/939cc865e90e9e15578d44228b6fdf69cf3b39f4/NppyPluginDll.cpp#L101) (GitHub)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you can't, unless you make the resulting lamba_functor a global variable.

In that case, you could declare a function that invokes it:

```
void uglyWorkaround() {
    globalLambdaFunctor();
}
```

and set `pFunc` to `uglyWorkaround()`.

**EDIT**
Just a sidenote: if you are binding static text to the function call, you may completely omit `bind()` call and write just:

```
void wrapper() {
    func(TEXT("console.write('test')"));
}
```

and set `pFunc` to `wrapper()`.

Comment: +1: This is the standard workaround for this problem. Usually, your callbacks can receive a `void *` as parameter, to pass along context. [This FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.2) explains it in more detail.

Comment: However, this skips over the problem of `globalLambdaFunctor`'s type, which isn't easily solved, since `bind()` returns something that depends on its arguments. And, of course, global variables come with a whole stack of problems...

Comment: Yes, well not very upliftin: [the "Solution" in line 101](https://github.com/Ciantic/NppyPluginDll/blob/master/NppyPluginDll.cpp#L101)

Comment: if you like I've come up with a solution that involves a little less typing and less error-prone.

Answer (score 4):

> Bind returns lambda_functor not a function pointer, so how can I cast this functor to function pointer?

I don't think you can. However, off the top of my head, I can think of several alternatives:

- Use `boost::function<void()>` (or `std::function()` if your compiler supports TR1 or C++11) instead of `void (*)()`.
  It has the ability to bind to just about anything with a somewhat compatible signature.
- Put the whole code into a template, make `PFUNCPLUGINCMD` a template parameter, and let function template argument deduction figure out the exact type. 
  That's a variation on the former, actually, where you would use the result of `bind()` directly instead of having `boost::function` abstract away the gory details.
- Create a wrapper that calls the functor returned by `boost::bind()`.
  A function template might help to let the compiler figure out the exact types and generate a suitable function, although I haven't tried to do that. However, since you cannot use the result of `bind()` as a template argument, but need to have give the function access to it nevertheless, you will need a global variable for this. (The ability to avoid this is one of the main advantages of function objects, a very versatile of which is `std::function`.)
- Extend your `PFUNCPLUGINCMD` callback type to support a user-provided parameter. For C callbacks, this usually is a `void*`. However, if you pass the address of the object returned by `bind()` to your callback, you would need to convert it into a pointer to the correct type - which, AFAIK, depends on the arguments provided to `bind()`. In order to avoid that, you'd need to pass something that abstracts away the exact type. Again, `std::function` comes to the rescue.

The first idea would be the best, but it requires you to be able to change `PFUNCPLUGINCMD`. The last one might be best when `PFUNCPLUGINCMD` needs to be compatible with C, as it uses the common C callback idiom.

Comment: I cannot change the struct or PFUNCPLUGINCMD it's directly from Notepad++ Plugin Interface, and thus I cannot add the extra parameter either. I tried to do this with templates, but I cannot assign non-template types runtime.

Comment: @Ciantic: If you can't change that, and if Notepad++' plugin API indeed sports user callbacks without user parameters, then all you can do is to store the result of `bind()` in a global variable (possibly of the type `function<void()>`) and write a wrapper function which invokes that.

Comment: @sbi: Okay, I believe ya. But hold on as I get the code online, this is most retarded way to do this. Is this fixed in C++0x with anonymous functions: `pFunc = []() { func(statement); }`?

Comment: @Ciantic: It would be, if it weren't for the fact that the compiler will turn lambda functions into function objects... Really, if you need to have certain data passed to some callback someone else calls, I know of three possible ways (in decreasing preference): 1) using a function object, 2) passing a `void* userdata` around, and 3) a global variable. Somewhere that data has to be kept, and if you don't have anything attached to the callable entity (function object), and the function that calls the callback won't pass on any state to it, then there's only global data, as bad as that might be.

Comment: @sbi: I did it with [global funcs @ GitHub](https://github.com/Ciantic/NppyPluginDll/blob/master/NppyPluginDll.cpp#L101), not very neat.

Comment: @Cianti: "Long story short: C++ does not allow to create functions or lambda functions with valid C function pointers runtime" That is nonsense. As I've tried to explain: You have a function ___plus some state___ you want to have passed to that function, and your API doesn't support passing it. In C++ that would be easy, but you need C function pointers, and ___it's C that cannot do that___.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, unless you want to write your own Just-In-Time compiler. Alternatively, if you control the receiving code, then you could use a `boost::function<>`, which *will* accept a variety of function types, including pointers *and* function objects like those produced by `boost::bind`.