# boost::bind return a function object which is the argument for a function that requires pointer

Tags: c++, linux, boost, bind, function-pointers

I am doing C++ coding on Linux about boost::bind.

The return data type of boost::bind is a function object, which is an input argument to another function bridge_set_pound_var_func.

But, bridge_set_pound_var_func's input argument must be a function pointer.  bridge_set_pound_var_func's interface cannot be changed.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost;

class myA
{
 public:

     int bridge_set_pound_var_func( int (*pound_var_func)(const char *, char *, void *), void *arg ) { std::cout << "bridge_set_pound_func is called " << std::endl ; return 0; }
 };

 class myC
 {
  public:
        myA *myOA;
        int func(const char * poundVar , char * t1, void * t2);

        int myCCall() { myOA->bridge_set_pound_func( (boost::bind(&myC::func, this)), (void *)this ); return 0;}

 };

 int myC::func(const char * poundVar , char * t1, void * t2)
 {
     std::cout << "myC::func is called " << std::endl;
     return 1;

  }

 int main()
 {
      myC myCO ;
      myC *m1p = &myCO ;
      m1p->myCCall() ;

      return 0 ;
 }

 // EOF
```

I got compile error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to 

 'myA::bridge_set_pound_func(boost::_bi::bind_t<int (&)(const char*, char*, void*), boost::_mfi::dm<int ()(const char*, char*, void*), myC>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<myC*> > >, void*)'


  note: candidates are: int myA::bridge_set_pound_func(int (*)(const char*, char*, void*), void*)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

### And, the interface of bridge_set_pound_var_func cannot be changed because it needs to be called by many other functions.

This is the new code that work. But, "myC::func is called"  is not printed, why ?

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#include <iostream>
using namespace boost;

class myA
{
 public:

 int bridge_set_pound_var_func( const boost::function3<int, const char *, char *, void *> f, void *arg )  { std::cout << "bridge_set_pound_var_func is called " << std::endl ; return 0; }

};

 typedef  int (*funcPtr)(const char *, char *, void *) ;

 typedef boost::function0<int&> boostBindFuncType;

 class myC
 {
  public:
   myA *myOA;
   int func(const char * poundVar , char * t1, void * t2);

   int myCCall()
   {

     std::cout << "myCCall is called " << std::endl;
     myOA->bridge_set_pound_var_func( (boost::bind(&myC::func, this, _1, _2, _3)), (void *)this );

     return 0;

   }

 };

 int myC::func(const char * poundVar , char * t1, void * t2)
 {
  std::cout << "myC::func is called " << std::endl;
  return 1;

 }

 int main()
 {
    myC myCO ;
    myC *m1p = &myCO ;
    m1p->myCCall() ;

   return 0 ;
 }
```

I cannot change the interface of bridge_set_pound_var_func, which is called by many other functions. Is is possible to transform boost::bind returned function object to a function pointer?

Comment: Side note: why not use the C++11 `functional` library?

Comment: this is a small part of a very large project. how to use C++11 functional lib ? thanks

Comment: Using better names would make your example code more comprehensible.  `myA` and `myC` don't tell me anything, and you don't use `f1` anywhere in the sample code.  `f1` seems to be `myA::bridge_set_pound_func()` -- correct?  And so the `myA` object is not actually *yours*, and that is the interface that is fixed?

Comment: Just make a helper function and pass a pointer to the helper function. You can code the helper function to do whatever you want, including invoking a `boost::function`.

Comment: I can use a helper function with boost::bind returned data as input. But, how to transform the boost::bind data type to a function pointer so that bridge_set_pound_var_func can be called correctly ? thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I cast or convert boost bind to C function pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962960/how-can-i-cast-or-convert-boost-bind-to-c-function-pointer)

Comment: All, it works, I post the new code in the original post. But, "myC::func is called " is not printed, why ? thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally the final `void *` argument passed to callbacks is user defined data. If this is the case for you you can create a helper function that will let you pass functors. the only trouble is that you need to ensure that the user data exists until the callback will no longer be called - and that will depend a lot on your program structure. I'm just going to leak the object as thats the easiest way to ensure it continues to exist. ( Though you'll also have problems with the existance of the containing `myC` object ).

```
class myC
{
  public:
    myA *myOA;

    //NOTE: I've removed the void* ptr here, which should be user data.
    // If you still need it you'll need to bind it away at functor creation time.
    int func(const char * poundVar , char * t1);

    int myCCall()
    {
      //TODO: Fix this intentional leak.
      boost::function<int(const char*, char*)> * fn = new boost::function<int(const char*,char*)>( boost::bind(&myC::func,this) );
      //Call our helper function instead of `set_pound_func`.
      set_pound_func_with_functor(myOA, fn );
      return;
    }
};

// Function that is really passed to `set_pound_func` when 
// set_pound_func_with_functor is called.
// It converts the user data back to a boost function and calls it.
int pound_func_with_functor(const char* d1, char* d2, void* user_data)
{
  boost::function<int(const char*,char*)> * fn = static_cast< boost::function<int(const char*, char*) >( user_data );
  return (*fn)(d1,d2);
}

//Helper function to make set_pound_func work with boost functions instead.
//NOTE: You are required to ensure the fn argument exists for long enough...
void set_pound_func_with_functor( myA * myOA, boost::function<int(const char *, char *)> & fn )
{
   myOA->bridge_set_pound_var_func( &pound_func_with_functor, &fn );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no ways to convert `boost::bind` result to function pointer.

Use `boost::function`

```
int bridge_set_pound_var_func
( const boost::function<int(const char *, char *, void *)>& f, void *arg )
```

call as

```
myOA->bridge_set_pound_var_func( (boost::bind(&myC::func, this, _1, _2, _3)),
(void *)this );
```

or use `template parameter`

```
template<typename Func>
int bridge_set_pound_var_func( const Func& f, void *arg )
```

call as in first case.

You cannot convert result of `boost::bind` or `boost::function` to function-pointer.

I think read this will be interestring.

[demote boost::function to a plain function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282372/demote-boostfunction-to-a-plain-function-pointer)

In your case - you cannot use `target`, so, look at answer of Ian

Comment: Thanks, but errors: testBoostBind.cpp:11: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
testBoostBind.cpp:11: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
testBoostBind.cpp: In member function 'int myC::myCCall()':
testBoostBind.cpp:33: error: no matching function for call to 'myA::bridge_set_pound_var_func(boost::_bi::bind_t<int, boost::_mfi::mf3<int, myC, const char*, char*, void*>, boost::_bi::list4<boost::_bi::value<myC*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3> > >, void*)'
testBoostBind.cpp:11: note: candidates are: int myA::bridge_set_pound_var_func()

Comment: The syntax  function<int(const char *, char *, void *)> is correct ?

Comment: @runnerfrank : With any non-ancient compiler, yes, that's correct. What version of what compiler are you using?

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/78300b4602cc0348ce5a1ba4ce1b5c19 yes, it's correct. Look at `boost::function` documentation. If your compiler cannot use this syntax - use old (i.e. `function<int, const char*, char*, void*>`).

Comment: gcc version 4.3.2 20081105 (Red Hat 4.3.2-20) (GCC

Comment: @ForEveR, I added #include <functional>, but the same error even though I used const boost::function<int, const char *, char *, void *>& f

Comment: Another thing is, the interface of bridge_set_pound_var_func cannot be changed.

Comment: @runnerfrank not functional. `boost/function.hpp`.

Comment: @ForEveR, yes, I included <boost/function.hpp>, const boost::function<int(const char *, char *, void *)>& caused more errors: function_template.hpp: In static member function 'static R boost::detail::function::function_obj_invoker3<FunctionObj, R, T0, T1, T2>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0, T1, T2) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<int (&)(const char*, char*, void*), boost::_mfi::dm<int ()(const char*, char*, void*), myC>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<myC*> > >, R = int, T0 = const char*, T1 = char*, T2 = void*]':

Comment: @runnerfrank have no ideas. code should compiles well. you can use old syntax (i.e `boost::function<int, const char*, char*, void*>`)

Comment: @ForEveR, yes, I used  const boost::function<int, const char *, char *, void *>& f, but error: rror: wrong number of template arguments (4, should be 1)

Comment: @runnerfrank give a complete small example of your problem pls (if you use syntax as <int(...)>

Comment: @runnerfrank : When you're using the old/portable syntax, you need to use `boost::function2` rather than `boost::function` (see [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#id1545352)). In any case, GCC 4.3.2 is more than recent enough to use the syntax shown in the answer, so you must have some other problem we're not seeing. What version of Boost are you using?

Comment: My boost version: BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_33_1"

Comment: @runnerfrank http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#id2688219

Comment: if I used  const boost::function2<int(const char *, char *, void *)>& f, error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)

Comment: if I used const boost::function2<int, const char *, char *, void *>& f, wrong number of template arguments (4, should be 3)

Comment: All, it works, I post the new code in the original post. But, "myC::func is called " is not printed, why ? thanks !

Comment: @runnerfrank : You are using an **ancient** version of Boost -- 1.33.1 is from Dec. 2005. Do yourself a favor and update to something released within the last 7 years. ;-]

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can pass as a function pointer is a function. No function objects, no lambdas, no nothing. Just global functions.

Comment: "*no lambdas*" Captureless lambdas are fine. "*Just global functions.*" Static member functions are fine.

Comment: Strictly, both of those are directly equivalent.