# Dynamically generated partial applications of a function to be passed to a struct as function pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda, anonymous-function, stdbind

So basically I am a complete beginner to a C++ but I have to face this complicated problem.
I basically have to design some strategy to a simple "dice poker game" similar to the one from Witcher. I came up with a strategy that relies on 4 parameters and I want to analyze which combination of parameters yields the best results by brute-forcely trying all of those combinations.
The strategy is represented by this struct:

```
typedef struct SOLUTION
{
    const char Name[32];
    const char ShortName[8];
    void(* Init)();
    int(* AI)(int, int, int, int);
}
SOLUTION;
```

Now, what I have is a "highly" parametric function:

```
static int AI_noRiskVar (int a, int b, int c, int d, int opponent_id, int bet, int state, int dice) {
    //do some stuff based on parameters a, b, c, d and the rest of parameters (which represent the game actual state)
}
```

Along with that, I have a simple API, that enables me to test any number of strategies against each other. All I have to do is to put them into an array of `SOLUTION` structs.

I came up with this plan, that tries to make use of `std::bind function`, which should be able to partially apply my `AI_noRiskVar` function to some parameters a, b, c, d:

```
SOLUTION Solution[83521]
int kauntr = 0;
for (int a = 3; a < 20; ++a) {
    for (int b = 3; b < 20; ++b) {
        for (int c = 3; c < 20; ++c) {
            for (int d = 3; d < 20; ++d) {
                // the identification of which struct contains which strategy is not important now
                Solution[kauntr] = (SOLUTION){"fixed length string of 31 chars", "7 chars", NULL, std::bind(&AI_noRiskVar, a, b, c, d)};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create an array of structs of which every one would have one combination of those a, b, c, d parameters partially fed into its AI function, i. e. have every possible configuration of the strategy tested via one of the generated structs.
Problem is, that the std::bind does not return a partially applied function of exactly type `int* (int, int, int, int)` but of type `_Bind(int*(int, int, int, int))`

Any suggestions on how to fix the type problem? Or am I missing something critical?
I had my hands on C, and almost all other major programming languages, but not C++ and I feel really lost even in the syntax arount types.

EDIT1:
I am not able to change the definition nor declaration of `struct SOLUTION` so i need to get exactly to the type described above. Is it even possible?
Also, if you are to present some C++ specific library functions or methods, could you please show how to use them in the context of my problem, it would help me understand the C++ way of coding.

Comment: Don’t try to get a function pointer from a function binding arguments: it won’t work. Essentially function pointer can’t capture additional state. Instead, use a `std::function<void(int, int, int, int)>`. These behave similar but *can* capture state.

Comment: In C++ you don't need to `typedef` structs and classes, just write `struct SOLUTION {...};`, then you can still use it like you already do in your code. Note that it's a bit weird to write struct names in all-caps; I suggest you only capitalize the first letter, and variables of that type should start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I cast or convert boost bind to C function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962960/how-can-i-cast-or-convert-boost-bind-to-c-function-pointer)

Comment: I cannot change the SOLUTION struct definition. Also, the whole API is predefined for me. It was written by a more of a C person, which I am too.